# How to export MySQL workbench database for Java application runs in other computers?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I developed a Java application connecting to MySQL database through a localhost connection.

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection conexao = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/bd_sensores", "root", "rootadmin");
```

I want to run the application on other computers. To do that I need to export the database, and the information already recorded. I think I need to create an installer and install it on other computers, but I need to change local and type of database.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a properties file that has the following properties:

- driver class name
- Database Host
- Database Port

as well as username.

Read the db configurations from this properties file and then load the driver and prepare your jdbc url.

Also, you can export your database through mysql workbench to a .sql file that will create a db script to run on another database. Use 'Manage Export / Import' functionality of workbench under 'Server Administration'

Comment: I exported the database from the mysql workbench. From what I understood was through a dump. Can I make a connection through that file?

Comment: Yes, you need to read the db configuration from properties file and then get a connection. Pass this configuration parameters to your code u've posted above.